# Difference between malloc() and simple declaration in fixed sizes

Tags: c, double, malloc, difference

Let assume that I want to get space for an array of *x* `double`, *x* being an integer.

Can someone explain me the difference between

```
double myArray[x];
```

and

```
malloc(x*sizeof(double));
```

excepted the fact that `malloc()` returns a `void` pointer ?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double myArray[x];` Here memory is

1. declared on stack
2. Declared at compile-time, hence faster
3. Accessible only in the scope of the declaring function,( globally if declared in global scope)
4. Will be freed if the declaring function returns
5. generally used when the size of array is known at compile time

`myArray = malloc(x*sizeof(double));` Here memory is

1. declared on heap (except for variable length arrays(C99) which are allocated on stack as pointed by Malina, read more [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html))
2. Declared at run-time, hence slower
3. Accessible wherever the myArray variable is accessible
4. Will be freed when `free(myArray)` is called or the program exits
5. generally used if the size of array is unknown at compile time

Comment: Declared on stack and Accessible only locally. Not true if is declared global or static.

Comment: Declared on stack only if constant-sized array. In C99, variable-sized arrays are on the program's internal automatic memory.

Comment: @Malina can you explain further. I am hearing this term - "program's internal automatic memory" for the first time

Comment: @Malina , VLAs are also allocated on the stack, aren't they?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html a good reading imo.